# MIPS registers $v0/$a0

Tags: assembly, mips

I understand that `$v0, $v1` are function result registers with `$v0` being 32-bit, `$v1` 64bit.

I also understand that `$ao-$a3` are function argument registers that hold integer type variables.

I understand that neither of these are preserved across function calls however what I don't understand is there literal use in MIPS? In what circumstances would we need to use these registers?

Comment: It is just the MIPS calling convention `$a`, `$v` registers store function arguments, return values respectively. However you can store them like you want into `$a`, `$v`, `$t`, but its gets messy with the complexity of the program.

Comment: all registers have the same length. That means both $v0 and $v1 have a size of 32 bit in MIPS32 and 64 bit in MIPS64

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use them if you plan on calling other functions that use the MIPS ABI (Application Binary Interface). It's a way for different code modules to agree on a common way of interfacing with one another. Imagine the mess if each programmer or compiler chose their own set of registers for passing arguments and return values.

Let's look at what a C compiler generates for a short piece of code:

```
int multwoplusone(int arg)
{
    return arg*2 + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    i = multwoplus1(i);

    return 0;
}
```

If we compile this (and look only at the relevant pieces of the generated assembly) we get:

```
multwoplusone:
    sll $2,$4,1  # $2 is $v0, $4 is $a0
    j   $31      # $31 is $ra
    addiu   $2,$2,1

...

main:
    ...

    li  $4,5            # 0x5
    lw  $25,%call16(multwoplus1)($28)
    .reloc  1f,R_MIPS_JALR,multwoplus1
1:  jalr    $25
    nop
```

As you can see, when `main` calls `multwoplusone` it first places the argument (5) in `$a0` (`$4`). `multwoplusone` then shifts this value left one bit (i.e. multiplies it by two), saves the result in `$v0` (`$2`), and then adds 1 to that in the delayed branch slot as it returns back to the caller. The caller (`main` in this case) can then assume that the return value will be in `$v0`, and do something with that value if it wants to.

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, but in the line; sll $2,$4,1  # $2 is $v0, $4 is $a0... Would the '1' take the register $a1?

Comment: The `1` in `sll $2,$4,1` is an immediate; i.e. the literal value 1.

Comment: Just to further this, if a register `$t0` was to hold the value `0x00008000` , what would the effect of this line be on `$t2`? `slt $t2, $t0, $zero`

Comment: It should be set to zero, since `0x00008000 < 0` is false.